# Convert stream video/x-ms-asf to audio and pipe it to stdin of sox

Tags: sound, streaming, pipe, soundconverter, sox

### Short story

I'm trying co convert something which seems to appear a video stream (to be precise it's a FM radio streamed to the internet via http://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3) of type `video/x-ms-asf` to audio to further pass it to `sox` to pass if further to [PiFmRds](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds/blob/master/README.md) like here

```
sox -t mp3 STREAM_URI -t wav -  | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -audio -
```

### Long story

What I need it for? One particular FM radio station in my house which I want to listen very much has very bad reception. It works well when I receive it from the internet and pass, e.g. from tablet, via AUX to my Hi-Fi system. But I want to listen to it like any other station (via FM) so I'd like to have 'raspberry pi' which receives this stream from internet and then creates a local FM transmission which is received on my Hi-Fi.

### What I'm able to do

I'm able to do such things for other streams but this one FM radio station decided to publish their transmission is some awkward `video/x-ms-asf` format which I cannot then pipe to the `pi_fm_rds` script.